# 'Post' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url' Django

Tags: django, sitemap

I am trying to create a sitemap in Django but I am getting an error

```
'Post' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
```

Here is my anotherfile/sitemap.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from somefile.models import Post

class site_map(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.8

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.time_stamp
```

and here is my somefile/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    number=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
    time_stamp=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to determine the paths in the sitemap, you need to implement a `get_absolute_url` for the model(s) for which you make a sitemap, so:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    number=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
    time_stamp=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('name-of-some-view', kwargs={'para': 'meters'})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

With [**`reverse(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) you can calculate the URL based on the *name* of the view, and parameters that the corresponding path needs.

Comment: Will the get absolute url value match my post slug?

Comment: @user16241015: if you need the slug, then in the `kwargs=...`, you will need to pass the value for that slug

Comment: @user16241015: if the path thus looks like `path(''posts/<slug:slug>/', some_view, name='post-detail')`, then we reverse with `reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})`.

Comment: I want my sitemaps url same as Slug (in Post model). can I achieve this by  kwargs={'slug': self.slug}

Comment: @uesr16241015: that depends on the `path(..)` you constructed to view (the details) of that post...

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but it simply sounds like your Post model doesn't have a get_absolute_url method.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.location

> If location isn't provided, the framework will call the
> get_absolute_url() method on each object as returned by items().

Model.get_absolute_url()

Define a get_absolute_url() method to tell Django how to calculate the canonical URL for an object. To callers, this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.

For example:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/post/%i/" % self.id
```